# Does DynamoDB support update operations like relational db

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, operation

I know we can do update by two operations, first get the primary key by querying the db, and then update it by put operation. But does DynamoDB support update by one operation as the relational db (such as mysql)? Since two operations will cost more time in network transferring.

My situation is as:
I have a table A with fields **ID, Name, Location, Value**.

And name+location can uniquely define a row. 
So now I want to update the field "Value" when Name and Location satisfied some condition, but I don't know the ID. So if I use mysql, then I can update it by "Update A set value = XXX where name = "abc" and location="123"". 
But when I use dynamoDB, I have to first get the primary key ID. 
Then use the Key to update the item. So my question is that does DynamoDB also support similar update operation as mysql does.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chen hit it on the nose.  Joey, the situation you described (Get followed by a Put) is equivalent to 2 mysql functions

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE key = x

   UPDATE TABLE 
   SET var = param
   WHERE key = x
```

Do you see how the Select/PutItem aren't part of the update process? As long as you have the keys, you don't need to perform a query.  I'm assuming you're performing the GetItem before the PutItem request because the PutItem replaces the entire item/row (i.e. deletes all attributes not specified in the Put request).

So if the original item looked like: *< key-id=1, first-name=John, last-name=Doe, age=22>*

and you perform a PutItem of: *< key-id=1,location=NY>*

The final item looks like: *< key-id=1,location=NY>*

If you perform an UpdateItem in place of PutItem then you would instead get:

*< key-id=1, first-name=John, last-name=Doe, age=22, location=NY>*

Here's a link for using the UpdateItem with Java. There also examples using .net and php

[UpdateItem for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelJavaItemCRUD.html#LowLevelJavaItemUpdate/)

Comment: My situation is as:
I have a table A with fields ID, Name, Location, Value. 
And name+location can uniquely define a row. So now I want to update the field "Value" when Name and Location satisfied some condition, but I don't know the ID. So if I use mysql, then I can update it by "Update A set value = XXX where name = "abc" and location="123"". But when I use dynamoDB, I have to first get the primary key ID. Then use the Key to update the item. So my question is that does DynamoDB also support similar update operation as mysql does.
Thanks!

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support the functionality you're describing, but I suggest you read over the documentation/developer's guide. From what I understand, you don't even need an ID or you could let ID be an attribute.

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support the functionality you're describing, but I suggest you read over the documentation/developer's guide especially about hash and range keys. The fix to you're problem is the data schema. Since _name_ and _location_ are unique, you set hash-key = _name_ and range-key = _location_ (or vice-versa, choose for the hash key that will be the most diverse), that way you can update the row in one step. You don't even need an _ID_ or you could let _ID_ be an attribute.  Here's the link [Data Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but Update Item will consume 1 operation only it will get hash key value and update it if exists else will create new Item (up-to 1 kb item)

here is the link for reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#CapacityUnitCalculations

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the primary key first. If you know the primary key, you don't need to get anything and you can simply use the [UpdateItem API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) call to update your item.

If that still isn't clear, please edit your question and add some code samples of what you are trying to do.